# Grails 2.4.2 and mail plugin 1.0.6 error

Tags: grails

Anyone else having issues with the mail plugin 1.0.6 and Grails 2.4.2?

This works fine:

```
mailService.sendMail {
    to "test@test.com"
    bcc "test@test.com"
    from "test@test.com"
    subject "test"
    body "test mail"
}
```

But when using view templates such as :

```
mailService.sendMail {
    to "test@test.com"
    bcc "test@test.com"
    from "test@test.com"
    subject "test"
    html  view:"/mail/test", model:[test:"test"]
}
```

I get "Cannot get property 'config' on null object errors" at

Around line 65 of MailMessageContentRenderer.groovy

65:    template.make(model).writeTo(out)

Not sure how to troubleshoot this. Any advice appreciated. I am trying to send from a controller.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

You need to render that template/view with the `html` method:

```
sendMail {
  to "john@g2one.com"
  subject "Hello John"
  html g.render(template:"myMailTemplate")
}
```

You can also use `body` method like this:

```
sendMail {
  to "john@g2one.com"
  subject "Hello John"
  body( view:"/emailconfirmation/mail/confirmationRequest", 
      plugin:"email-confirmation", 
      model:[fromAddress:'bill@microsoft.com'])
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alidad. Still getting the same error with those suggestions.

Comment: What do you have in those views? Try to debug it with a simple view first, make sure it is just a simple html.

Comment: <img src="${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL }/assets/logo.png"/>  is what caused problems. I passed grailsApplication:grailsApplication along with the model and all works now. I guess DI in the templates for grailsApplication object isn't working the same way. Not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Great, since you are using asset pipeline, you might not even need to create that path, something like this `<asset:image src="logo.png" width="200" height="200"/>` should take care your path.